# Does angulars $resource support etags?

Tags: angularjs, http, http-headers, angular-resource, etags

I'm seeing contradicting answers  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25004605/4642530 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/29067231 and the docs don't mention if they support it or how to handle etag if not. Anyone know?

Comment: I updated my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25004605/237012 . Are you using jQuery full or jqLite (default, that's built into angular)?

Comment: Thanks. I was for an ionic project and I wasnt using jQuery. I ended up handling this issue server side using nodeJs with the "request" and "modified" modules

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those answers are contradictory... However, besides that lone SO answer, I can find no evidence that `$resource` automatically tracks/sends ETags (the "If-None-Match") header.

I think the clearest evidence is that searching the [source for ngResource](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js) shows no mention of the "If-None-Match" header, nor the string "ETags".

Comment: For what it's worth, on a [different SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25004605/114558), someone mentioned that the rumored `If-None-Match` support actually originates in jQuery, not ngResource.